# Elastic search client in go fail to index more than one record

Tags: database, go, elasticsearch

I'm writing a simple service which send a report to elastic search database every time a user hit an end point. everything seemed  very simple at the beginning but then I realized that the elastic-search client cannot send more than one request per running the rest of the requests will just hang in the air and eventually will return timeout error.

I should mention that when I'm creating elastic-search client for every index request or when sending the requests using the curl format it works perfectly fine but when I use a single client it fails.

the following code demonstrate my problem. instead of sending all 100 indexRequest the program sends just one and will throw error with the rest. I spent already two days trying to see what I'm doing wrong but couldn't solve the problem

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v6"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v6/esapi"
)

func main() {
    cfg := elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: []string{
            "http://172.31.1.85:9200",
            "http://172.31.1.85:9201",
        },
    }
    es, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
        body := `
    {"test": "test"}
    `
        req := esapi.IndexRequest{
            Index:        "test",
            DocumentType: "",
            DocumentID:   strconv.Itoa(i),
            Body:         strings.NewReader(body),
            Refresh:      "true",
        }

        // Perform the request with the client.
        res, err := req.Do(context.Background(), es)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error getting response: %s\n", err)
            return
        }
        defer res.Body.Close()

        if res.IsError() {
            log.Printf("[%s] Error indexing document ID=%d\n", res.Status(), 100)
        } else {
            // Deserialize the response into a map.
            var r map[string]interface{}
            if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
            } else {
                // Print the response status and indexed document version.
                log.Printf("[%s] %s; version=%d", res.Status(), r["result"], int(r["_version"].(float64)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.